# How to add new link_to_add_association blank form at the top of all saved fields instead at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
= form_for [:update, @user_comments], url: [:udpate_comments, :update, @user] do |f|
  = f.fields_for :user_comments do |comment_fields|
    = render 'user_comment_fields', f: comment_fields
    = link_to_add_association "Add Comment", f, :user_comments, class: 'btn btn-secondary'

  = submit_button(f)
```

I want 'Add Comment' button at the top and new comments blank form should be added at the top of all comments. 
Just like this:

**Add Comment Button**

[Blank comment form]

[Comment 3]

[Comment 2]

[Comment 1]

Right now the new comment blank form is getting added to the end of all comments.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owner a.add_fields").
      data("association-insertion-method", 'before').
      data("association-insertion-node", 'this');
});
```